# Copying a string character by character in java

Tags: java, string

I have two strings and I am trying to copy one into another. How I can copy character by character a string into another in Java?.

Comment: Strings are immutable, why do you need to copy one? Why character by character?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by *"copy one into another"*? Do you mean `abc` copied into `bcd` turns to `abcbcd` or another logic?

Comment: Abc becomes bcd

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable objects in Java, which means that after they are instantiated, they will not change internal state. Instead, if you want to modify a String, you will always get a new String.

Now, to your question. If you want to copy a String chararcter by character this is highly inefficient, since you would create a new String object each time you copy a character. Luckily, there are plenty of other options.

```
String a = "a";
String b = "b";

String c = a + b; // "ab"
String d = a.concat(b); // "ab"
```

If you simply want to copy a String, you can do the following:

```
String e = a; "a"
```

Why does that work? As stated earlier, Strings a immutable, thus a new String with the same content is created. You can think of it as `String e = new String(a)`, which is slightly less performant (and therefore an antipattern), but also works.